# How to mask URL opened by Applet?

Tags: java, applet

If I use the following lines of code in Java I will be redirected to a newpage.html in the same window and frame where the applet's HTML page is (page.html). I am trying to mask the URL so that it still displays page.html in the address bar of the browser when I am redirected to newpage.html.

How would I do this?

```
URL url = new URL(getCodeBase().getProtocol(), getCodeBase().getHost(), getCodeBase().getPort(), "/newpage.html");
getAppletContext().showDocument(url, "_self");
```

Answer (score 3):

For security reasons, you can't do that.

Comment: Thank you. Can I use JavaScript instead in my html file to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to give a proper answer without understanding the rational for doing this.

However, maybe `page.html` can load a file which uses an iframe, and the iframe reloads. This way the page URL will still be `page.html`.